# Medium.js not working - 'Medium is not defined'

Tags: javascript, html

According to the [author](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/), something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <!-- JS for Medium -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-core.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-classapplier.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jzaefferer/undo/master/undo.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jakiestfu/Medium.js/master/medium.min.js" defer></script>
<!-- CSS for Medium -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jakiestfu/Medium.js/master/medium.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="editor"></div>

        <script>
            new Medium({
                element: document.getElementById('editor')
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

should work perfectly, but I keep getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Medium is not defined - Line 16

Am I doing something wrong here? I've spent the last 2 hours on this and no luck...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defer` attribute sets the script to run at last--after the page loads. So, the code run before Medium.js is loaded. There two possible solutions. You could remove that attribute to load the library and its components promptly. Or add an event listener when the whole page including the script:

```
window.onload = function(){
     new Medium({
         element: document.getElementById('editor')
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem until I realized that I missed all the dependencies. This particular error seems to be generated by Rangy being missing.

```
 <head>
    <script src="rangy-core.js"></script>
    <script src="rangy-classapplier.js"></script>
    <script src="undo.js"></script>
    <script src="medium.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="medium.css">
</head>
```